# What Python libraries do I need to do computational physics?

Tags: python, scipy

I need to install Python to do some undergraduate level computational physics (course, not research). What library do I need? Scipy only?

Comment: I don't see how anyone can possibly help you answer this. NumPy and SciPy might be enough, but without seeing your course syllabus and comparing it to what those libraries offer, it is impossible to know. Fortunately with pip, you can just install more libraries if you need them.

Comment: The easy installer for python libraries. Try googling it.

Comment: Hi Kyson and welcome to scicomp!  I've closed your question because its scope is too broad.  Depending on what kind of physics you'll be modeling, you could potentially add inumerously many packages.  Furthermore, it sounds like you would best benefit from asking your instructor or reading your syllabus rather than asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably need something to visualize your output such as `Matplotlib`. I have used it extensively during my undergrad and PhD (on-going) for day-to-day work and reports and it's excellent:

http://matplotlib.org/

I would also advise familiarizing yourself with the basic `NumPy` functions and syntax (`NumPy` is a dependency of `SciPy`) so that you can test out small solutions via the interactive python prompt (`iPython`).

In terms of documenting your progress (very important for any assessed work), check out the `iPython` notebook. This is web browser based and allows you to store and run your code blocks in the browser, interspersed with comment boxes. You can also insert $\LaTeX$ equations. Here's a fantastic series of examples by Lorena Barba's CFD group:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/barbagroup/CFDPython/blob/master/lessons/01_Step_1.ipynb

To restore the interactivity, you will need to download the .ipynb file and run using the `iPython` notebook in a terminal [if on *Nix].

Another option is to install Enthought Canopy - it's a python distribution specifically aimed at scientists and analysts. The free academic version comes with several hundred plugins for tasks such as image analysis, in addition to the basic modules mentioned above. I've used it extensively and particularly like the facility for updating/downloading new packages very easily:

https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/

Comment: Thanks G_Morgan, do you know how Enthought Canopy compare with Anaconda?

Comment: I've not actually used Anaconda sorry - I will take a look this evening and get back to you with some comparison if you like. By then I daresay you'll have some more posters. Extra info on your course will help.

Comment: that's very kind of you

Comment: No problem, I'll continue to update my answer with any extra relevant info too.

Comment: I had a look at Anaconda in comparison to Canopy - the Canopy Academic version seems to have a slight edge in terms of the number and variety of packages included. None of them are deal-breakers so unless you have specific needs based on your course, just go with whichever you like the look of. Probably best *not* to try installing both at the same time though, that could get a little messy.

Comment: I use Anaconda because it has python3 support.

Comment: @MaxHutchinson That's a good point - a lot of scientific python packages are based on Python 2.7. What are the advantages of it being hooked up to Python 3?

Comment: @G_Morgan I think its silly to learn and write code in a language which will *eventually* die.  The counter-point is that, as you point out, some libraries still don't have Python3 implementations.  I don't know if its 'a lot,' and I've never had problems.  In any case, Anaconda provides both, so if you go with Python2.7 and then someone hands you some Python3 code, you already know how Anaconda works and can quickly set up a new environment.